# Elasticsearch transport client: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.buffer.CompositeByteBuf.addComponents

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

Below is my sbt file. When I am running from my IDE it works fine all records are being indexed in elastic search. But when I do sbt assembly and submit that fatjar to spark cluster it throws below error. Let me know what is wrong with assembled fatjar.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.buffer.CompositeByteBuf.addComponents(ZLjava/lang/Iterable;)Lio/netty/buffer/CompositeByteBuf;
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Utils.toByteBuf(Netty4Utils.java:78)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.sendMessage(Netty4Transport.java:449)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.sendMessage(Netty4Transport.java:91)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.internalSendMessage(TcpTransport.java:976)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.sendRequest(TcpTransport.java:958)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequestInternal(TransportService.java:520)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequest(TransportService.java:465)
```

sbt file for my project

```
import sbt.Keys._

name := "compute-layer"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.6.1" excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.logging"))
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.6.1" excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.logging"))
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka_2.10" % "1.6.0" excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.logging"))
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch.client" % "transport" % "5.1.1" excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.logging"))
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.7"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.7"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.1"
libraryDependencies += "io.netty" % "netty-all" % "4.0.4.Final"

resolvers ++= Seq("clojars" at "https://clojars.org/repo",
  "conjars" at "http://conjars.org/repo",
  "plugins" at "http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release",
  "sonatype" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/",
  "Online Play Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/simple/maven-releases/"
)


assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}


//libraryDependencies += "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.6.2"
```

Comment: did you fix the error ? :(

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar problem, with as following:

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that works for me was changing ElasticSearch settings to use netty 3

```
yourMapSetting.put("transport.type","netty3")
yourMapSetting.put("http.type", "netty3")
```